# Is there a mac utility that can magnify parts of the screen?

Tags: macos, applications

For some teaching efforts, especially running through tutorials, I'd like to zoom in on parts of my screen to show a room-full of people small text from the projected screen. Is there an OS X utility that will magnify sections of the screen as I move my cursor over it? I know about **OmniDazzle** but the magnifier is somewhat clunky.

Comment: You could also press control and scroll which will zoom in the *whole* screen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to *System Preferences*, then *Accessibility*. There will be a column on the left for Zoom, which you can use a keyboard shortcut to activate.

[image: macOS Accessibility, Pictures]

Once activated, hitting <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> will zoom the screen.

Comment: How do you do that from terminal?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which version of osx you are using, in 10.8.2 go to system preferences, accessibility, zoom, then under zoom style select picture-in-picture. The zoom box will follow your cursor. Older versions had this option not sure of the steps for other versions.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following apps:

- [Zoom It](http://www.zoomitapp.com)
- [Virtual Magnifying Glass](http://magnifier.sourceforge.net)

There are at least one other, but Zoom It app is the one that most reviews recommend. I use it with a 40 inch 4k display. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Digital Color Meter can do that but unfortunately AFAIK its window is not resizable.